# What does "book-wise" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I stumbled upon an online quiz and one of the questions is

> Do you consider yourself intelligent, book-wise?

What does "book-wise" mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contexts such as OP's, ***X-wise*** means *when considered specifically in the context of X*. It's a construction commonly used to create "nonce" terms (one-off coinages whose precise meaning is specific to the context, but normally obvious to the reader/audience in that context).

Here are a couple of instances from Google Books for ***dinner***-wise (just a noun I chose at random). Note that they're separated by over 150 years, showing that the construction has been around a long time with no significant change in how it can be used...

> *Gentlemen, I incline not dinner-wise. And why? — I have dined already*
>    [(Brother Jonathan, 1842)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22incline%20not%20dinner-wise%22)
>
> *I don't know what the wife can do dinner-wise but there'll be something*
>    [(Death at Hallows End, 2008)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wife%20can%20do%20dinner-wise%22)

Perhaps unwisely, OP's cited context blurs the distinction between *intelligence* and *knowledge*. Almost certainly the quiz-setter is asking whether you think you're good at [book learning](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/book-learning). That's to say, are you good at absorbing information from books (rather than personal experience), ***and/or*** good at passing exams and succeeding in an academic context (as opposed to having [practical skills](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/practical+skills), [common sense,](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/common%20sense) etc., being types of "intelligence" often claimed by "non-academics").

---

In OP's *specific* case, ***book-wise*** primarily restricts the context of "intelligence" to the ability to absorb information from (academic) textbooks. But it's easy to imagine a context where the restriction is significantly different...

> *I get through several tabloid newspapers and magazines every day. But **book-wise** I'm not much of a reader, so I hardly ever visit the local library.*

...where in *that* context the speaker may well be referring to books as a source of entertainment (novels and other works of fiction), rather than "information" as such.

---

EDIT: I've just realised that some learners may find OP's specific example confusing because they might understand ***intelligent*** as meaning ***wise*** (having ***wisdom***). But etymologically that word is unrelated to the suffix usage. From [Your Dictionary...](http://www.thesaurus.yourdictionary.com/wise)

> The suffix **-wise** has a long history of use to mean “in the manner or direction of,” as in **clockwise, otherwise,** and **slantwise.** Since the 1930s, however, the suffix has been widely used in the vaguer sense of “with respect to,” as in
>    *This has not been a good year saleswise.*
>    *Taxwise, it is an unattractive arrangement.*

Answer (score 0):

This is from or likely at least somewhat related to a slang term *book smarts* - [this](http://scottberkun.com/2010/book-smarts-vs-street-smarts/) explains it well.  A contrasting and related term is *street smarts*.

It's part of a broader view that there are different kinds of intelligence, and "book smart" is just one of them.

Excerpt from the linked article:

> Book smarts, as I’ve framed it, means someone who is good at following
>   the rules. These are people who get straight A’s, sit in the front,
>   and perhaps enjoy crossword puzzles. They like things that have
>   singular right answers. They like to believe the volume, and
>   precision, of their knowledge can somehow compensate for their lack of
>   experience applying it in the real world. Thinking about things has
>   value, but imagining how you will handle a tough situation is a world
>   away from actually being in one.